# AWS Lambda: module initialization error: TypeError

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy AWS lambda function and I have written code in express:

Code:

```
 var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var lampress = require('lampress');
    var request = require('request');
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

    // Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

    // Process application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // Index route
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello! I am a Chatbot designed to help you learn  Type "begin" to start a chat! You can type "begin" at any time to return to the first menu');
    });

    // for Facebook verification
    app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
        if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'xyz') {
            res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
        }
        res.send('Error, wrong token');
    });

    // Spin up the server
     app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('running on port', app.get('port'));
    });

    //figure out if your greeting text is working
    //need persistent menu?
    app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
        getStarted();
        greetingText();
        messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
        for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {

            event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
            sender = event.sender.id;
            if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            //code
            }
            if (event.postback) {
            //code
            }
            console.log('********2');
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    });

    exports.handler = lampress(app, function() {
        console.log("Server has started");
    });
```

Error:

```
 module initialization error: TypeError
        at lampress (/var/task/node_modules/lampress/index.js:82:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:829:23)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)*
```

I have proper node_modules in place. Why wont this work.

compressed zip structure
   --> index.js
   --> node_modules folder.

package.json:
"lampress": "^1.1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is at `exports.handler = lampress(...` as per the [lampress docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lampress) `lampress()` takes 2 arguments, the first a port number and the second a server. You've passed in a server for the first argument and a function for the second, so lampress throws a `TypeError`

The correct code would be:

```
exports.handler = lampress(<your port number>, app);
```

Comment: Thats for version 2.0.0. Installing lampress via ```npm install lampress``` installs 1.1.1 so the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lampress should be correct.

Comment: He didn't mention how he installed it. And more significantly, the stack trace of his error seems to be originating from a require statement.

Comment: I have installed version npm -v lampress
4.1.2 . I am not sure if I am in the right version packge.json has : "lampress": "^1.1.1" should

Comment: @suchu34 What would be the port name while deploying in AWS lambda: Heroku and openshift has : envirnment object which is process.env

Comment: I have created new function with the mentioned code format and I get the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008247/error-when-deploying-aws-lambda-deployment-package

Comment: @schu34 yes i did try

Answer (score 2):

FYI
For me, it was `source-map-support` that discarded the actual error message and stack trace.
Once I commented out the `source-map-support` import line then the error started showing the actual error message and stack trace.
https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support/issues/240

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you sourced the module, can you try:

```
require('./lampress');
```

Also, in your route handler, minor correction to avoid sending a response twice:

```
app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'xyz') {
        return res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
    }
    res.send('Error, wrong token');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction Sylon.changing require('./lampress'); I am facing module initialization error. Since It cannot find lampress node module.

Comment: Exact error:                                                                                              Error: Cannot find module './lampress'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)

Comment: I have created new function and I get the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008247/error-when-deploying-aws-lambda-deployment-package