# Error when deploying AWS lambda deployment package

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy AWS lambda function and I have written code in express:

Code:

```
 var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var lampress = require('lampress');
    var request = require('request');
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', (port));

    // Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

    // Process application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // Index route
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello! I am a Chatbot designed to help you learn  Type "begin" to start a chat! You can type "begin" at any time to return to the first menu');
    });

    // for Facebook verification
    app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
        if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'xyz') {
            res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
        }
        res.send('Error, wrong token');
    });

    // Spin up the server
     var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
       console.log('running on port', app.get('port'));
     });

    //figure out if your greeting text is working
    //need persistent menu?
    app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
        getStarted();
        greetingText();
        messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
        for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {

            event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
            sender = event.sender.id;
            if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            //code
            }
            if (event.postback) {
            //code
            }
            console.log('********2');
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    });

    exports.handler = lampress(port, server);
```

Error:

```
     START RequestId: Version: $LATEST
2017-02-02T16:58:58.055Z    undefined   running on port 5000
2017-02-02T16:58:58.112Z        Error: SecurityError: Request method not allowed
    at openOnSocket (/var/task/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-socket/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:191:13)
    at eventHandler.sendRequest (/var/task/node_modules/lampress/index.js:64:11)
    at eventHandler.handle (/var/task/node_modules/lampress/index.js:23:10)
    at /var/task/node_modules/lampress/index.js:87:13
END RequestId: e307361f-e968-11e6-b52d-7d8324fb6452
REPORT RequestId:   Duration: 99.26 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB  
RequestId:  Process exited before completing request
```

I have proper node_modules in place. Am I going somewhere wrong with port number and why methods are not accessible

When access the API I get:

```
{"errorMessage":"RequestId: xyz Process exited before completing request"}
```

compressed zip structure
   --> index.js
   --> node_modules folder.

package.json:
"lampress": "^1.1.1"

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: This happens, this didn't stop my API to work so Ignored this error since I get this error while deployment not in the actual code. I tried to search for many resources but failed to get answer at that time,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen on port 5000 for security reasons. You have to listen on a unix socket, like /tmp/mysock.

Answer (score 0):

> REPORT (Duration: 99.26 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms ).

Try to set more time for duration your code in advanced settings ->(Timeout).