# module initialization error TypeError in AWS Lambda with AWS SDK nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am writing some lambda's and In those lambda's I am using aws sdk to use some of the services, It's working fine for some service and it's not working for some services, in some services it say's module initialization error. What is wrong here, why some aws sdk modules only throw this error?

the error log from watch log:

```
START RequestId: dcbf2a88-d723-4a4e-8be9-896887150169 Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: TypeError
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/functions/routes/handler.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
END RequestId: dcbf2a88-d723-4a4e-8be9-896887150169
REPORT RequestId: dcbf2a88-d723-4a4e-8be9-896887150169  Duration: 38.90 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 69 MB
```

line number 4 in the error is object creation code

```
const text = new AWS.Textract({apiVersion: '2018-06-27'});
```

Comment: Hi, can you at least show us the code which throws the error?

Comment: Hi @kkesley, updated the post

Comment: You might want to look at similar [threads](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/issues/101) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992768/aws-lambda-module-initialization-error-typeerror).

Comment: I checked those links, it didn't work

Comment: what's in handler.js line 4? can you show us your **code**?